# Limits of integral over a region after substitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, hyperbolic-functions

I have the integral of a function $f(x,y,z)$ defined over the region $a<\sqrt{x^2-y^2-z^2}<b$; that is,
$$I\equiv \int_{a<\sqrt{x^2-y^2-z^2}<b}dxdydzf(x,y,z).$$
I realized that defining the variables
$$x=\rho \cosh \chi,\\
y =\rho\sinh \chi \cos \varphi,\\
z = \rho\sinh \chi \sin \varphi,$$
implies $a<\rho<b$, so
$$I=\int_a^b d\rho \int_{?_1}^{?_2} d\chi \int_0^{2\pi}d\varphi \rho^2\sinh \chi f(\rho \cosh \chi,\rho\sinh \chi \cos \varphi,\rho\sinh \chi \sin \varphi)$$
The factor $\rho^2 \sinh \chi$ corresponds to the Jacobian determinant.

How can I obtain the limits of integration for $\chi$? How is this done in general?

Comment: @zkutch Yes, $x^2-y^2-z^2=\rho^2(\cosh^2 \chi-\sinh^2 \chi\cos^2 \varphi-\sinh^2 \chi\sin^2 \varphi)=\rho^2(\cosh^2 \chi-\sinh^2\chi)=\rho^2$, so $\rho= \sqrt{x^2-y^2-z^2}$.  I don't know what you mean about it? not being a sphere.  I'm not using spherical coordinates.

Comment: @zkutch Hyperbolic cosine and sine satisfy such identity.